# DOMDocument Table Content Laravel Database

Tags: php, html, laravel, domdocument

I want to create a table content page using the DODocument method with Laravel. How do I use it? Then I want to get it from the database.

I have a code and I want to get it from the database and display it in the view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample table of contents</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table-of-contents">
     <h2>Table of Contents</h2>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section2">Section 4</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
<h1 id="introduction">Introduction</h1>
<p>This is an introduction section.</p>
<h2 id="section1">Section 1</h2>
<p>This is part 1.</p>
<h2 id="section2">Section 2</h2>
<p>This is part 2.</p>
<h2 id="section3">Section 3</h2>
<p>This is part 3.</p>
<h2 id="section4">Section 4</h2>
<p>This is section 4.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is 'the' domdocument method? What issue are you running into?

Comment: It appears that there might be a misunderstanding in the question. DOMDocument is not a method but rather a class in PHP that represents an entire HTML or XML document. It is part of the DOM extension in PHP and provides a convenient way to create, manipulate, and traverse HTML or XML documents using an object-oriented approach.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, but please read your question again and make it clear. No-one on earth can help you if you omit important information and you dont state what issue you're having